# save session/cookies with requests

Tags: python, http, http-request

I want to send a post request to a login form with the action /ShowLogin.xpl. I wrote a code using requests which sends an http request and sends post request with the user name & password credentials. How over, when I try to print out the content of the web page I still see the login page because the session or the cookie isn't saved. Can anyone help me?

The url is: https://www.xplace.com/ShowLogin.xpl

My code is:

```js
payload = {"j_username" : "myusername", "j_password" : "mypassword"}

with requests.Session() as s:
  webpage = s.post("https://www.xplace.com/ShowLogin.xpl", data=payload)

  # An authorised request
  r = s.get("https://www.xplace.com/ShowRecommendedProjects.xpl")
  print r.text
```

Comment: Did you check if the session/cookie was truly not saved?

Comment: Yes, I checked if the session/cookie is not saved. I tried to print all of the elements in r.cookies but it was empty. Someone have an idea?